# Node app crashes when receiving a duplicate email address E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: node.js

I have looked around at other questions about this error and every answer provided is a little different. Since my code is different then other people's its hard to identify the issue. When I run my node app and enter a duplicate email into the email field and proceed with the forum request the server crashes and throws this error:

```
BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: loginapp.users index: email_1 dup key:
```

This is saying, at least I think this is saying that the email I entered is already in use in the database. Which is what I want, but instead of crashing I would rather want it to send a message to the page saying "email already exists". My code is below any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

My only thought is maybe try catch to catch the error, then inform the user of the duplicate. If that is the correct thing to do I'm not all that sure how to do that with my current code setup.

```
// Register
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
    res.render('register');
});

// Login
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

// Register User
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var firstname = req.body.firstname;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // Validation
    req.checkBody('firstname', 'First Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('lastname', 'Last Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register',{
            errors:errors
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname: lastname,
            email:email,
            username: username,
            password: password
        });

        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
   User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null, user);
        } else {
            return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
        }
    });
   });
  }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
    req.logout();

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');

    res.redirect('/users/login');
});

module.exports = router;
```

App.js

```
// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a unique index on MongoDB user collection that's why mongo will throw this error and there is no way to override mongoose functionality easily so you have to handle that in code.

In your code, you are throwing error but you are not handling error anywhere that's why it crashes

```
User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
    if(err) throw err;  // <== this line
    console.log(user);
});
```

so instead of throwing the error, you can handle it there.

But the best way to handle is to first check the email before registering and if you don't want to do that use express's error handler to handle the error.
As you are using default express router then you will get callback function in the argument so utilize that to write common error handler

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res , next) {  // <== next function as callback
    // your code
    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
        if(err) {
            if (err.code == 11000 && err.message.indexOf('users.$email_1') > -1) {
              next(new Error('DUP_EMAIL'));
            } else {
          next(new Error('INTERNAL_ERROR'));
            }
          }
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

then in your app.js or server.js whatever your main express file if write following function to handle error

```
app.use('/', indexRoutes);  // router

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use((request, response, next) => {
    // response.status(404).send('NOT_FOUND');
});

// other type of errors, it *might* also be a Runtime Error
app.use((err, request, response, next) => {
    // your logic to send error
  req.flash('error_msg', mappingFile[err.message]); // mapping file is key value pair of code and user friendly messages
});
```

Comment: This will help me bypass the crashing for the error. But wont this also be bypassing the fact that I don't want duplicate email address to be registered? When a duplicate email address is entered I want it to catch that error and output "email already in use" returning user to /register.

Comment: As well I edited the code above to show part of my app.js file and I already have something like this implemented.

Comment: Yes, you have to write logic to check whether its email error or other error and then throw an error with a custom message and write one mapping file to map your error codes with user-friendly messages. editing answer to give you the basic idea.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Edited answer you need to do something like this, you can change the flow but something like this will work for you to show error and advantage here is you can use common error interface for whole app.

Comment: How did I create email as a unique index? I don’t have a tag in the schema saying it is unique.

Comment: This may not happen, but in past, if you have created a unique index and then removed it then you need to manually remove that index as mongoose is not able to remove them once it's created(I don't know about the current version, I have faced that years ago). but you told this is what you want so add that to schema.

Comment: Your right. I had set it as unique and then removed it thinking it wasn’t working. But I had also set username as unique: true in the schema but exception was never thrown for that. Any reason why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164405/discussion-between-ridham-tarpara-and-jimbob101).

Answer (score 0):

> in your code, you throw an error. never throw an error instead handle
>   the error in a proper way in your code to prevent to crash your server.

so handle like this.

```
 User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
     if (err) {
         if (err.code == 11000 && err.message.indexOf('users.$phoneNo_1') > -1) {

             // your custom logic here

         } else if (err.code == 11000 && err.message.indexOf('users.$email_1') > -1) {

             // your custom logic here
         } else {
             // your custom logic here
         }
     } else {
         // your custom logic here
     }

 });
```

Comment: This I can try.

Comment: @JimBob101 let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Will do. Heading off to bed for the night I’ll look more into it tomorrow.

Comment: @JimBob101 please accept answer if you think its working for you